# How to package front-end for deploy to nginx

Tags: angular, jhipster

I create a client only project using:

```
jhipster --skip-server --db mysql --auth jwt
```

successfully.

Now I want to generate a package (either dev or prod) which I want to deploy to nginx.

Following official guide I issued:

```
yarn webpack:build:dev
yarn webpack:build:prod
```

on Windows powershell, however I got the error:

> error Command "webpack:build:dev" not found
>   error Command "webpack:build:prod" not found

How to generate a package manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commands are wrong, check the `scripts` section in your project's `package.json`, it should be `yarn webpack:prod`

Comment: yes, yarn webpack:prod for prod and yarn webpack:build for dev.

Comment: I fixed the official doc.